# How to add an macro below tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How can I add an macro "Loi giai" which is bold and center below this tcolorbox and add contents after it (if needed).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,colback=white]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{vd}%[2D1B1]
    Đề bài
    \loigiai{
        lời giải
    }
\end{vd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide full your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `before lower` option and use `\tcblower` to create an upper and a lower part in your box. `tcolorbox` allows you to customise how the upper and lower boxes look, including the line between them (see §4.4 of the manual).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{qa}{%
  colframe=blue, colback=white,
  before lower=\begin{center}\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{lời giải}}\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{qa}
  Đề bài
  \tcblower
  lời giải
\end{qa}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]